# Typescript in React: defining a property on `this`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my non-tyepscript react component I had

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.delayedSearch = _.debounce((val) => {
        this.onQuerySearch(val);
    }, 1000);
}
```

for debouncing typing on an input field. Then on an input field I had `<input onChange={event => this.delayedSearch(e.value)}>`

Now, however, when I switch to Typescipt, my assignment of the `_.debounce` gives me an error:

`Property 'delayedSearch' does not exist on type 'UserSearch'.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your class doesn't declare to have this `delayedSearch` property, therefor the compiler can't understand what this property is.

In your class you should have something like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    private delayedSearch: (val: string) => void;

    componentWillMount() {
        // should be fine now
        this.delayedSearch = _.debounce((val) => {
            this.onQuerySearch(val);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```